# Elastic Search - Faceted Search - Attributes Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build an elastic search function to get the attributes from a project but i am having issues with building the correct aggregation for the attributes.

What i cannot manage it in each attribute name bucket, to ignore the filters for that attribute name so i can get all the buckets without those filters, while still applying the rest of the conditions.

Here is the current document structure

```
 Array
    (
        [_index] => products_ro
        [_id] => 46741098
        [_score] => 1
        [_ignored] => Array
            (
                [0] => product_description.keyword
            )

        [_source] => Array
            (
                [all_images] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => https://p1.akcdn.net/full/1045142034.redo-group-tamis-01-1570.jpg
                    )

                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [group_name] => General
                                [group_values] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [attribute_name] => Dulie sursa de lumina
                                                [attribute_value] => E27
                                                [attribute_name_search] => dulie-sursa-de-lumina
                                                [attribute_value_search] => e27
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [attribute_name] => Material lampa
                                                [attribute_value] => Metal
                                                [attribute_name_search] => material-lampa
                                                [attribute_value_search] => metal
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [attribute_name] => Numar soclu
                                                [attribute_value] => 3
                                                [attribute_name_search] => numar-soclu
                                                [attribute_value_search] => 3
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Casa si gradina
                        [1] => Lampa de perete, plafoniera, candelabru
                    )

                [categories_path] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => casa-si-gradina
                        [1] => lampa-de-perete-plafoniera-candelabru
                    )

                [currency] => lei
                [lang] => ro
                [product_slug] => smarter-plafoniera-tamis-01-1570-3-x-e27-negru-mat-aur-mat-01-1570
                [id_product] => 46741098
                [min_price] => 215
                [max_price] => 215
                [product_brand] => Redo Group
                [product_brand_slug] => redo-group
                [product_name] => Smarter Plafoniera tamis 01-1570, 3 x e27, negru mat + aur mat (01-1570)
                [product_image] => https://p1.akcdn.net/full/1045142034.redo-group-tamis-01-1570.jpg
                [product_description] => Dulie sursa de lumina E27Material lampa MetalNumar soclu 3 Ați găsit greşeli în descrierea produsului? Vă rugăm să ne trimiteți o notificare! Denumiri similare la Lampa de perete, plafoniera, candelabru Redo TAMIS 01-1570: TAMIS 01 1570, TAMIS011570, TAMIS01-1570 Galerie
                [rating_count] => 55
                [rating_value] => 4.2
                [rating_segments] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 14
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 55
                        [4] => 11
                        [5] => 77
                    )

                [seller_count] => 1
                [product_urls] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 8d49516af6518d3dababa82e6cd7d70c88b240d8
                    )

                [seller_list] => Array
                    (
                        [active_products] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [background_link] => 0
                                        [title] => Smarter Plafoniera tamis 01-1570, 3 x e27, negru mat + aur mat (01-1570)
                                        [comment] => Magazin de incredere
                                        [domain] => eco-lustre.ro
                                        [currency] => lei
                                        [condition] => New
                                        [direct_link] => https://eco-lustre.ro/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=5915
                                        [price] => 215
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [store_logo] => https://p1.akcdn.net/partnerlogosmall/158355.jpg
                                        [date_upd] => 2023-12-09 11:59:14
                                        [timestamp_added] => 1700616391
                                        [timestamp_updated] => 1702123154
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [categories_search] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Casa si gradina
                        [1] => Lampa de perete, plafoniera, candelabru
                    )

                [product_brand_search] => Redo Group
                [product_name_search] => Smarter Plafoniera tamis 01-1570, 3 x e27, negru mat + aur mat (01-1570)
            )

    )
```

Here is my current php function, my problem is in the "group_attributes" agg, i cannot make it ignore the filters foreach respective group.

```
public static function getBrandProducts($lang, $brand = null, $filters = [], $limit = 60, $offset = 0) {


$category_filters = false;
$price_from = 0;
$price_to = 999999999;

if(isset($filters['price_from'])){
     $price_from = (int)$filters['price_from'][0];
     unset($filters['price_from']);
}

if(isset($filters['price_to'])){
     $price_to = (int)$filters['price_to'][0];
     unset($filters['price_to']);
}

$banned_get = ['p','gclid','fbclid','ttclid','utm_source'];

  foreach($banned_get as $b){

    if(isset($filters[$b])){
        unset($filters[$b]);
    }

  }



if(isset($filters['categorii'])){
   
    if(!empty($filters['categorii'])){

        $category_filters = $filters['categorii'];
        unset($filters['categorii']);
    }

}



$brand_query = [];
$category_query = [];
$price_query = [];
$attribute_query = [];


$allDocuments = [];
$index_name = 'products_' . $lang;
$connection = self::getConnection($lang);


$attribute_query = $price_query = $category_query = $mustClauses = [['match' => ['product_brand_slug' => $brand]]];


foreach ($filters as $attributeName => $attributeValues) {
    $shouldClausesForAttribute = [];
    foreach ($attributeValues as $attributeValue) {
        $shouldClausesForAttribute[] = ['match' => ["attributes.group_values.attribute_value_search" => $attributeValue]];
    }

    $q = [
        'nested' => [
            'path' => 'attributes.group_values',
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => $shouldClausesForAttribute,
                    'minimum_should_match' => 1,
                    'must' => [
                        ['match' => ['attributes.group_values.attribute_name_search' => $attributeName]]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $mustClauses[] = $q;

        $brand_query[] =  $q;
        $price_query[] = $q;
        $attribute_query[] = $q;
        $category_query[] = $q;


}

if (isset($category_filters)) {

    $categoryShouldClauses = [];
    foreach ($category_filters as $category) {
        $categoryShouldClauses[] = ['term' => ['categories_path' => $category]];

    }
    if(!empty($categoryShouldClauses)){

        $q = [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => $categoryShouldClauses,
                'minimum_should_match' => 1
            ]
        ];

        $mustClauses[] = $q;   
        $brand_query[] =  $q;
        $price_query[] = $q;
        $attribute_query[] = $q;


    }

}




$price_query  = $mustClauses;

// Handle price range filter
$q = [
    'range' => [
        'min_price' => [
            'gte' => $price_from,
            'lte' => $price_to
        ]
    ]
];

$brand_query[] =  $q;
$category_query[] =  $q;
$attribute_query[] = $q;


$mustClauses[] = $q;



$params = [
    'index' => $index_name,
    'body'  => [
        'from' => $offset,
        'size' => $limit,
        '_source' => ['product_brand','product_slug','product_brand_slug','rating_count','rating_value','product_name', 'product_image', 'min_price', 'max_price', 'product_brand', 'product_brand_slug', 'id_product','lang','currency', 'sku','attributes', 'seller_count'],
        'post_filter' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => $mustClauses
            ]
        ],

        'aggs' => [


             
      'group_attributes' => [
        'filter' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => $mustClauses
            ]
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'nested_attribute_names' => [
                'nested' => [
                    'path' => 'attributes.group_values'
                ],
                'aggs' => [
                    'attribute_name' => [
                        'terms' => ['field' => 'attributes.group_values.attribute_name'],
                        'aggs' => [
                            'attribute_value' => [
                                'terms' => ['field' => 'attributes.group_values.attribute_value'],
                                'aggs' => [
                                    'exclude_filter_on_same_attribute_name' => [
                                        'filter' => [
                                            'script' => [
                                                'script' => [
                                                    'source' => "
                                                                String currentAttributeName = params['_key']; 
                                                                List mustClauses = params['mustClauses'];
                                                                for (Object clauseObj : mustClauses) {
                                                                    Map clause = (Map) clauseObj;
                                                                    if (clause.containsKey('nested')) {
                                                                        Map nestedMap = (Map) clause.get('nested');
                                                                        if ('attributes.group_values'.equals(nestedMap.get('path'))) {
                                                                            Map queryMap = (Map) nestedMap.get('query');
                                                                            Map boolMap = (Map) queryMap.get('bool');
                                                                            List mustList = (List) boolMap.get('must');
                                                                            for (Object item : mustList) {
                                                                                Map mustClause = (Map) item;
                                                                                if (mustClause.containsKey('match')) {
                                                                                    Map matchMap = (Map) mustClause.get('match');
                                                                                    if (matchMap.containsKey('attributes.group_values.attribute_name_search')) {
                                                                                        String filterAttributeName = matchMap.get('attributes.group_values.attribute_name_search').toString();
                                                                                        if (filterAttributeName.equals(currentAttributeName)) {
                                                                                            return false; // Skip this attribute name
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                return true; // Include the bucket by default
                                                            


                                                    ",
                                                    'lang' => 'painless',
                                                    'params' => [
                                                        'mustClauses' => $mustClauses
                                                    ]
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],


            'price_ranges' => [
          
                
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' =>  $price_query
                    ]
                ],

                'aggs' => [
                    'range' => [
                     
                        'range' => [

                            'field' => 'min_price',
                            'ranges' => [
                                            ['to' => 170],
                                            ['from' => 170, 'to' => 250],
                                            ['from' => 250, 'to' => 350],
                                            ['from' => 350, 'to' => 570],
                                            ['from' => 570]
                                ]
                        ],

                    ]
                ]
            ],



                'category_level_1' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            'bool' => [
                                'must' =>  $category_query
                            ]
                        ],
                    'aggs' => [
                        'primary_category' => [
                                    'terms' => [
                                        'script' => [
                                            'source' => "doc['categories'].size() > 0 ? doc['categories'][0] : ''",
                                            'lang' => 'painless'
                                        ]
                                    ]
                            
                        ]
                    ]
                ],

        ]
       
    ]
];


try {
    $response = $connection->search($params);
  
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle the exception as needed
     echo "<pre>";print_r( $e );echo "</pre>";
  //  return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
}


// Process hits
if (isset($response['hits']['hits'])) {
    foreach($response['hits']['hits'] as $hit){
        $allDocuments[] = $hit['_source'];
    }
}


$aggs = [];


if (isset($response['aggregations'])) {
    $aggs = $response['aggregations'];
}  


if(isset($aggs['group_attributes'])){
    if(isset($aggs['group_attributes']['nested_attribute_names'])){
          if(isset($aggs['group_attributes']['nested_attribute_names']['attribute_name'])){

             $aggs['group_attributes']  = $aggs['group_attributes']['nested_attribute_names']['attribute_name'];
        }
    }
}


if(isset($aggs['category_level_1'])){
    if(isset($aggs['category_level_1']['primary_category'])){
          if(isset($aggs['category_level_1']['primary_category'])){

             $aggs['category_level_1']  = $aggs['category_level_1']['primary_category'];
        }
    }
}


if(isset($aggs['price_ranges'])){
    if(isset($aggs['price_ranges']['range'])){
          if(isset($aggs['price_ranges']['range'])){

             $aggs['price_ranges']  = $aggs['price_ranges']['range'];
        }
    }
}





$totalCount = $response['hits']['total']['value'] ?? 0;
return ['products' => $allDocuments, 'total_count' => $totalCount, 'aggs' => $aggs];
```

}